# What is the proper way of calling d.dispose() or s.cancel() method?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

In RxJava2 there is a new method introduced in Observer interface and Subscriber interface named -

```
interface Subscriber<T>{             
 @Override
 public void onSubscribe(Subscription s)
 {
      s.cancel();
      s.request(5);
 }
....
}
```

and

```
interface Observer<T>{             
     @Override
     public void onSubscribe(Disposable d)
     {
          d.dispose();
     }
    ....
    }
```

And I saw that **onSubscribe()** method always called very first time even before **onNext(T t)**, and I read that docs too and found that its use is for disposing the resource if your work is done with that particular Observable.

The question is how we can know initially that our job is done and **dispose** or **cancel** the source or connection between source and consumer?
So what is the better way to call **d.dispose()** and **s.cancel()** or **s.request(7)**?

Comment: I m not sure I understand what you're asking. `how we can know initially that our job is done ` what do you mean?

Comment: I mean when I can decide that this is the right time to call d.dispose(), because after just calling, the connection is gonna be loss with the observable. So when should i call it, on what condition?

Answer (score 3):

The stream can terminate in two ways:

1. Error
2. Complete

In both cases, as far as I know, you don't need to call dispose/cancel. As indeed the [reactive stream contract says](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html):

> When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its
>   observers, this ends the subscription.

Of course, you can stop your stream in any moment, before it ends with an error or because it completes. In these cases you have to call dispose/cancel. Use:

- `dispose()` for `Observable`
- `cancel()` for `Flowable`

About `request()` method, you need it if you want to establish a "reactive pull", and I don't think it is related with `cancel`. You can found more information [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure)

Answer (score 2):

It is rare you have to call those methods because `take` and similar other operators will limit the stream for you. In addition, the helper classes `DisposableObserver` and `DisposableSubscriber` manage the `Disposable`/`Subscription` for you.

In some special consumers, you'd want to call `Subscription.request(1)` from `onSubscribe()` and then from `onNext()` but there is no practical reason to call either `request()` or `cancel()` from `onError()` or `onComplete()` and it has no effect either.

For example, the following code will apply backpressure via `request(1)` because it consumes a sequence and forwards it to an asynchronous post-processing logic that otherwise is not RxJava aware:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

source.subscribe(new Subscriber<Data>() {
    Subscription upstream;
    @Override public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        upstream = s;
        s.request(1);
    }

    @Override public void onNext(Data t) {
        exec.submit(() -> {
           if (t.isValid()) {
               process(t.details);
               upstream.request(1);
           } else {
               upstream.cancel();
               exec.shutdown();
           }
        });
    }

    @Override public void onError(Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    @Override public void onComplete() {
        exec.shutdown();
    }
});
```

Again, this is rare in general. On regular `Subscriber`s, you only have to call `s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE)` because the callstack-blocking nature ensures the last upstream stage won't overwhelm the `onNext`:

```
source.subscribe(new Subscriber<Data>() {
    Subscription upstream;
    @Override public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        upstream = s;
        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override public void onNext(Data t) {
       if (t.isValid()) {
           process(t.details);
       } else {
           upstream.cancel();
       }
    }

    @Override public void onError(Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override public void onComplete() {
    }
});
```

In conclusion, `onComplete` is called when there is no further data available and you call `cancel` when you want to indicate no further processing should take place even if more data would be available.